# Which indexes to use for Fulltext search + group by year and month

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

**Final purpose of the query**

For a query q, I want execute a query like this one

```sql
SELECT publication_year_month, count(*)
FROM content
WHERE content.title_content_vector_column @@ plainto_tsquery(q)
GROUP BY publication_year_month
```

and then use the response set to plot a timeline where X is the "year and month" and Y is the amount of pages that have **q** in their title or content

**Here's the table "pages"**:

```
id bigserial,
title text,
content text,
publication_date timestamptz,
publication_year_month text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    EXTRACT(year from timezone('UTC'::text, publication_date))::text || '-' || EXTRACT(month from timezone('UTC'::text, publication_date))::text
) STORED,
title_content_vector_column tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(title, '')), 'A') ||
    setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(content,'')), 'B')
) STORED
```

current **indexes**:

```
CREATE INDEX title_content_vector_column_index ON pages USING GIN (title_content_vector_column);
CREATE publication_year_month_index ON pages (publication_year_month);
```

This table currently has around 10 million entries.

**Average lengths of the fields:**

title: 70 characters

content: 2500 characters

**Average length of q:** 3-15 characters

**EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)**

```sql
BEGIN;
SET track_io_timing = ON;
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) 
SELECT publication_year_month, count(*)
FROM "pages" 
WHERE "pages"."title_content_vector_column" @@ plainto_tsquery('covid')
group by publication_year_month;
commit;
```

```
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=1545072.81..1545123.48 rows=200 width=40) (actual time=116900.267..116906.868 rows=145 loops=1)
  Group Key: publication_year_month
  Buffers: shared hit=4668680 read=1378357
  I/O Timings: read=299893.279
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1545072.81..1545119.48 rows=400 width=40) (actual time=116900.244..116906.737 rows=363 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=4668680 read=1378357
        I/O Timings: read=299893.279
        ->  Sort  (cost=1544072.79..1544073.29 rows=200 width=40) (actual time=116774.952..116774.966 rows=121 loops=3)
              Sort Key: publication_year_month
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 30kB
              Buffers: shared hit=4668680 read=1378357
              I/O Timings: read=299893.279
              Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 30kB
              Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 30kB
              ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=1544063.15..1544065.15 rows=200 width=40) (actual time=116774.622..116774.657 rows=121 loops=3)
                    Group Key: publication_year_month
                    Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 48kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=4668663 read=1378356
                    I/O Timings: read=299893.261
                    Worker 0:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 48kB
                    Worker 1:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 48kB
                    ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on pages  (cost=3608.29..1543252.39 rows=162152 width=32) (actual time=541.155..116415.508 rows=131676 loops=3)
                          Recheck Cond: (title_content_vector_column @@ plainto_tsquery('covid'::text))
                          Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 491168
                          Heap Blocks: exact=19022 lossy=55745
                          Buffers: shared hit=4668663 read=1378356
                          I/O Timings: read=299893.261
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on title_content_vector_column_index  (cost=0.00..3511.00 rows=389166 width=0) (actual time=390.092..390.092 rows=395027 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (title_content_vector_column @@ plainto_tsquery('covid'::text))
                                Buffers: shared hit=1 read=87
                                I/O Timings: read=34.501
Planning:
  Buffers: shared read=1
  I/O Timings: read=0.763
Planning Time: 3.625 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 33
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 31.246 ms, Inlining 251.247 ms, Optimization 483.000 ms, Emission 237.400 ms, Total 1002.892 ms
Execution Time: 116910.434 ms
```

**Timings after applying suggestions from @jjanes**

```
SET work_mem TO '16MB';
set jit to off;
```

Result from same EXPLAIN... query above:

```
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=143025.80..143206.16 rows=200 width=40) (actual time=12186.346..12242.578 rows=334 loops=1)
  Group Key: publication_year_month
  Buffers: shared hit=14 read=171189
  I/O Timings: read=32950.322
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=143025.80..143202.16 rows=400 width=40) (actual time=12186.333..12241.426 rows=945 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=14 read=171189
        I/O Timings: read=32950.322
        ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=142025.78..142155.97 rows=200 width=40) (actual time=12122.609..12160.284 rows=315 loops=3)
              Group Key: publication_year_month
              Buffers: shared hit=14 read=171189
              I/O Timings: read=32950.322
              ->  Sort  (cost=142025.78..142068.51 rows=17092 width=32) (actual time=12122.590..12136.735 rows=67290 loops=3)
                    Sort Key: publication_year_month
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 6268kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=14 read=171189
                    I/O Timings: read=32950.322
                    Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 6200kB
                    Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 6212kB
                    ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on pages  (cost=402.17..140824.12 rows=17092 width=32) (actual time=144.976..11943.176 rows=67290 loops=3)
                          Recheck Cond: (title_content_vector_column @@ plainto_tsquery('china'::text))
                          Heap Blocks: exact=57768
                          Buffers: shared hit=1 read=171184
                          I/O Timings: read=32950.286
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on title_content_vector_column_index  (cost=0.00..391.92 rows=41022 width=0) (actual time=130.883..130.884 rows=201871 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (title_content_vector_column @@ plainto_tsquery('china'::text))
                                Buffers: shared hit=1 read=57
                                I/O Timings: read=66.051
Planning:
  Buffers: shared read=1
  I/O Timings: read=0.011
Planning Time: 0.298 ms
Execution Time: 12243.247 ms
```

**PC specs**
The DB is currently running under WSL2 on Windows inside a Docker container.

It has 4GB of RAM and 2 CPU cores assigned.

The WSL2 itself is located on a SSD disk.

**Table Statistics**

Row Count estimate: 8 million

Disk Space: 44GB

Rel Size: 7.3GB

**Main question**:

What can I do in order to have a result in about average 2 seconds?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  Please show the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.  Turn on track_io_timing first, if possible.  How long are the values of "title" and "content" typically going to be, and for that matter "q"?

Comment: @jjanes info added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your work_mem is too low.  You should increase it until the lossy blocks on the parallel bitmap heap scan goes away.  Your shared buffers hit and read both seem bizarrely high for the number of rows returned.  I'm guessing that that is mostly TOAST, and if you get rid of the rechecks driven by lossy pages, it might also get rid of the need to deTOAST the data (to do the rechecks with).  Even if that doesn't speed it up a lot, it would be nice to see the new numbers once work_mem is higher.

Since most of your time is waiting for IO, faster disks wouldn't hurt, nor would enough RAM to keep the table in cache (how big is the table?  How much RAM do you have?) but you may need to take special steps to get it there and keep it there, even if it does fit.

Finally, what if you disable JIT?  It is taken up a lot of time (half of your desired run time) and I doubt it is helping much, if any.

Another approach would be to precompute and store the aggregates for every lexeme for every year-month.  This would only work if each query was a single lexeme, though.

So increasing the work_mem made it about 10 times faster (but for processing half as many rows, so really 5 time faster per row), and made the number of buffer reads look more reasonable, essentially one buffer read for each exact block (because I think the exact block reports only the parallel leader's count, while buffer reads report the sum of the three processes).  So that is probably a config change to make permanent.  But you are still 6 fold away from your goal even for this smaller set.

But still essentially all your time is spent reading the table pages from disk.  Your disks do not seem slow by any means, but still slow given what you want to do.  Maybe you can get more throughput out of them by increasing effective_io_concurrency so you can have even more requests in-flight at the same time.  How effective this is would depend on your SSD hardware and drivers, as well as how effective your 2 virtualization layers at passing the requests up to the native layer.

> Disk Space: 44GB
> Rel Size: 7.3GB

Is disk space for the entire database and rel size for this one table?  If so, your are not all that far from getting the whole table to fit in RAM, for this one table.  If you can afford to do that to the neglect of all other data.

As for index types, I was wondering if the [RUM index](https://github.com/postgrespro/rum) 3rd party extension might help you out by enabling you to store the year-month along with the lexeme in the RUM index, so you would not need to visit the table at all.  But looking through the options, I don't see one that would do it.  You might want to take a second look though.

Comment: thank you for the reply. It seems like increasing work_mem and disabling jit indeed sped up the queries, added the results to my question above. The database is running inside a WSL2 under Docker, that might be the cause for slower IO operations. It has allocated 4GB or RAM for the whole WSL2, and nothing else is running there besides the DB. Added also statistics to the question above.

Comment: BTW what is your definition of lexeme in this case?

Comment: a lexeme would be each row returned by `select distinct lexeme from tbl, unnest(va)`

Comment: Ok, it seems that increasing the work_mem to 256MB did bring much better results. Now the query executes in under 30 seconds, which is great.

Comment: I also tried moving the DB to a linux system with an SSD as well, and it seems like here the perfomance is even better. With the same allocated memory set to 256MB and effective_io_concurrency set to 10, the queries finish in 5 seconds or less. The SSD's in question are Crucial MX100, not top of the art by far, but better than spinning disks.

Comment: That disk space is only for that table, yes. So, the RAM I have allocated for the DB is only 4GB, so I guess the table does not fit in RAM. Also, it's expected for the table size to grow continuously. But eventually a good option for more performant queries in the long run :)

Comment: Thank you for the RUM index suggestion, I'll have a look at it as well if I see that in the near future it makes sense to try some other type of index.